# ffmpeg copy a part of a video wrt to milliseconds accurately

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to copy a part of video.

I am using mpv to view the video. I get the start time and end time from it.

ffmpeg -i "main.flv" -ss 01:54:34.340 -to 02:01:13.073 -c copy copied.mp4

the problem i am facing is the video does not start from 01:54:34.340, it starts from 01:54:34.608

so its shifting the start poistion.

Is there any way i can start from the exact millisecond position or form that particular frame.

or is there command to mention start frame number and end frame number. For that mpv also should tell me the frame numbers in ths OSD

the output of the above command is

```
Input #0, flv, from 'main.flv':
  Metadata:
    author          : 
    copyright       : 
    description     : 
    keywords        : 
    rating          : 
    title           : 
    presetname      : Custom
    creationdate    : Thu Aug 25 04:50:55 2016
                    : 
    videodevice     : VidBlaster
    avclevel        : 31
    avcprofile      : 77
    videokeyframe_frequency: 5
    audiodevice     : Realtek HD Audio Input
    audiochannels   : 2
    audioinputvolume: 100
  Duration: 03:55:58.86, start: 0.033000, bitrate: 855 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(tv), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 819 kb/s, 30.30 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 22050 Hz, stereo, fltp, 49 kb/s
Output #0, mp4, to 'copied.mp4':
  Metadata:
    author          : 
    copyright       : 
    description     : 
    keywords        : 
    rating          : 
    title           : 
    presetname      : Custom
    creationdate    : Thu Aug 25 04:50:55 2016
                    : 
    videodevice     : VidBlaster
    avclevel        : 31
    avcprofile      : 77
    videokeyframe_frequency: 5
    audiodevice     : Realtek HD Audio Input
    audiochannels   : 2
    audioinputvolume: 100
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 819 kb/s, 30.30 fps, 29.97 tbr, 16k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 22050 Hz, stereo, 49 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=  frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=  frame=11906 fps=8002 q=-1.0 Lsize=   41574kB time=00:06:38.75 bitrate= 854.1kbits/s speed= 268x    
video:38866kB audio:2336kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.904480%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `-ss` is specified after the input, it seeks to the first keyframe after the specified time. So, specify an earlier time, or place `-ss` before the input. In any case, if the start time isn't a keyframe, the cut file won't start from there.

Comment: Ok. now i am using mencode to start precisely. but there is no -to option like ffmpeg

Comment: mencoder -ss 00:40:26.673 -endpos 00:00:90.047 -oac pcm -ovc copy krsna.avi -o krsnacut1.avi